# Return the less loss possible in a given array

Tags: javascript, arrays

How do I return the minor loss in a given array?

Maybe I'm not so clear, let's go to a pair of examples.

Given the array [5, 10, 3], **MUST** return 2 (5 - 3), which is the less loss possible.

The array [30, 10, 54, 76, 1, 4, 35] **MUST** return 6 (10 - 4) which is the less loss possible.

The array size is variable, as the given numbers, but must return the less loss possible.

My code until now:

```js
function solucao (precos) {
  const newArr1 = []
  const newArr2 = []
  for (let i = 0; i < precos.length; i++) {
    newArr1.push(precos[i])
    newArr2.push(precos[i])
  }
}
```

My algorithm is to compare two arrays... but this solution isn't the best!

Comment: Two things.
1) I don't think your solution will work at all. If both arrays are the same array then how will it get different numbers and know which is better? You are only going through each element in the same order so there is no logic. I think you should at least make it functional before asking for help. Best practice is off-topic for SO and is better suited to [codereview.se] But we can help with making it work
2) This is a nit pick but isn't 4-1 better than 10-4 in your second example? Or have I misunderstood it?

Comment: Yes. I removed my solution and I'm trying another way.
You misunderstood.

I can put the entire announcement here about the exercise.

Comment: Find and print the minimum amount of money that Leticia must lose if she buys the house and resells it in the coming years.

Input

The entry will always be an array of integers of varying size containing the price of the home for years to come.

Output - Always be an integer representing the minimum loss that Letícia will have.

Sample Input - [5, 10, 3]
Sample Output - 2

Letícia buys the house in the 1st year at price = 5 and resells it in the 3rd year at price = 3 resulting in a loss of 5 - 3 = 2.

Sample Input - [30, 10, 54, 76, 1, 4, 35]
Sample Output - 6

Comment: So this is homework then? Just checking as it will influence the best way to give you an answer. For more information how on we handle homework questions please see: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822) Homework questions are fine and this question doesn't really have any major flaws but just linking that for you to look at just to help not have other users have a go at you if this is homework. Just trying to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summarizing your question:

We have an array (ordered) of numbers. I want to see the "minimum difference" between "higher indexed element" and "lower indexed element", but that "minimum difference" must be a "negative number".

How do I summarize it:

We have an array or ordered numbers. I want to see the "minimum difference" `(loss or gain from buy-then-sell transaction)` between "higher indexed element" `(sell year)` and "lower indexed element" `(buy year, where sell year must be higher than buy year)`, but that "minimum difference" `(loss or gain from buy-then-sell transaction)` must be a "negative number" `(because the question ask for a loss, if it's positive number then it is called gain)`

How to do it:

- start by listing all possible "difference", stored in dictionary `arrStartEnd`
- then filter the result: discard all positive number (since it's not a loss), then apply absolute (Math.abs), stored in dictionary `arrStartEndNegativeOnly`
- lastly, find the minimal number in the result of previous step

When doing this kind of homework/test problem, in my opinion, the most important step is understanding the problem (summarizing the question above)

```js
var arr1 = [5, 10, 3];
var arr2 = [30, 10, 54, 76, 1, 4, 35];
console.log("problem 1: "+JSON.stringify(arr1));
//console.log(arr1);
console.log("problem 2: "+JSON.stringify(arr2));
//console.log(arr2);

function countMinimumLoss(arr) {

// start by listing all possible "difference", stored in dictionary arrStartEnd
var arrStartEnd = {};
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  for(var j = i+1; j < arr.length; j++) {
    arrStartEnd["loss"+i.toString()+"to"+j.toString()] = arr[j] - arr[i];
  }
}
//console.log(arrStartEnd);

// then filter the result: discard all positive number (since it's not a loss)
var arrStartEndNegativeOnly = {};
for (var key1 in arrStartEnd) {
  //console.log(key1);
  if(arrStartEnd[key1] < 0) arrStartEndNegativeOnly[key1] = Math.abs(arrStartEnd[key1]);
}
//console.log(arrStartEndNegativeOnly);

// lastly, find the minimal number in the result of previous step
var minimumLoss = 999999;
var minimumKey = null;
for (var key1 in arrStartEndNegativeOnly) {
  if(minimumLoss > arrStartEndNegativeOnly[key1]) {
    minimumLoss = arrStartEndNegativeOnly[key1];
    minimumKey = key1;
  }
}

//console.log(minimumKey);
//console.log(minimumLoss);

return minimumLoss;

}

var ans1 = countMinimumLoss(arr1);
var ans2 = countMinimumLoss(arr2);

console.log("answer 1: "+ans1.toString());
console.log("answer 2: "+ans2.toString());
```